# How to read storage when using ValueQuery

Tags: rust

I have the below code, if you see I am storing the ContractSender struct as OptionQuery.

Later on, I am trying to read the data from the Struct, but was not able to.

```
#[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn contract_sender)]
    pub(super) type ContractSender<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::AccountId, Contract<T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>, OptionQuery>;


    #[pallet::storage]
    #[pallet::getter(fn contract_receiver)]
    pub(super) type ContractReceiver<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::AccountId, Contract<T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>>, OptionQuery>;

    #[pallet::event]
    #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
    pub enum Event<T: Config> {
        /// Sign Contract
        ContractEvent(T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>, u64, u64, u64),
        /// Lock funds
        Locked(T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>),

        /// Unlock funds
        UnLock(T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>),

        /// Transfer
        Transfer(T::AccountId, T::AccountId, BalanceOf<T>),
    }

    #[pallet::error]
    pub enum Error<T> {
        /// The requested user has not stored a value yet
        NoValueStored,
        /// Expiring Date was wrong/older than current date
        WrongExpiringDate,
        /// Contract is signed by the same addresses
        SameAddressError
    }

    #[pallet::call]
    impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {

        /// Sign contract between two addresses
        #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::sign_contract())]
        pub fn sign_contract(
            origin: OriginFor<T>,
            to: T::AccountId,
            amount: BalanceOf<T>,
            work_days: u64,
            take_action_days: u64,
        ) -> DispatchResultWithPostInfo {
            // Check if Tx is signed
            let from = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            // Check if the sender and receiver have not the same address
            ensure!(from != to, Error::<T>::SameAddressError);

            // calculate how many blocks per day gets generated
            let prod_block_per_sec = 6;
            let day_per_second = 86400;
            let prod_block_per_day = day_per_second / prod_block_per_sec;

            let current_block_number: u64 = frame_system::Pallet::<T>::block_number().try_into().unwrap_or(0);
            let work_days_in_block_number = current_block_number + (work_days * prod_block_per_day);
            let take_action_days_in_block = work_days_in_block_number + (take_action_days * prod_block_per_day);

            //Creating a Contract object
            let contract = Contract {
                origin: from.clone(),
                to: to.clone(),
                amount: amount.clone(),
                current_block_number: current_block_number.clone(),
                work_days_in_block_number: work_days_in_block_number.clone(),
                take_action_days_in_block: take_action_days_in_block.clone(),
            };

            // Save in storage the sender and the contract
            <ContractSender<T>>::insert(from.clone(), &contract);
            // Save in storage the reciever and the contract
            <ContractReceiver<T>>::insert(to.clone(), contract);
            //Throw Contract event

            let work_days_in_block_number = <ContractSender<T>>::get(&from).work_days_in_block_number;

            Ok(().into())
        }
```

When I am trying to read from the storage and get the work_days_in_block_number value but not possible.
Error:

```
 error[E0609]: no field `work_days_in_block_number` on type `Option<Contract<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId, <<T as pallet::Config>::Currency as Currency<<T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId>>::Balance>>`
     --> /Users/elioprifti/substrate-node-template/pallets/escrow/src/lib.rs:161:68
      |
  161 |             let work_days_in_block_number = <ContractSender<T>>::get(&from).work_days_in_block_number;
      |                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0609`.
  warning: `escrow` (lib) generated 3 warnings
  error: could not compile `escrow` due to previous error; 3 warnings emitted
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

As you said, you are using `OptionQuery`.

So the value you get is an `Option` value.

```rust
let maybe_contract_sender = <ContractSender<T>>::get(&from);

if let Some(contract_sender) = maybe_contract_sender {
    let work_days_in_block_number = contract_sender.work_days_in_block_number;
}
```